# Is it possible to do this with null coalescing operator?

Tags: php

With `isset()`, you can do this:

```
$foo = [];
$baz = [];
$bar = isset($foo['bar'], $baz[$foo['bar']]) ? $baz[$foo['bar']] : '';
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with null coalescing like:

```
$bar = ($foo[$bazz['foo']]) ?? ''; //Undefined variable: bazz
```

Im expecting `$bar` to be:

```
$bar = '';
```

[??: Null coalescing operator](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)

Comment: what is the value of $bazz?

Comment: They are all not set

Comment: One of the cool things about programming is that you can often try stuff like this out for less than $0.001 in electricity costs. Why don't you type it in a script and try it?

Comment: @Loek OP tried - *//Undefined variable: bazz*

Comment: @splash58 Then there's his answer right?

Comment: Sorry guys I have edited my question to include what I expect, please check!

Comment: `$bar = (@$foo[$bazz['foo']]) ?? ''; `
 http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/eea3f8d2c1ca7513d1872d3c66da3031f4dbc9b1

Comment: The trick works @splash58, thank you. Put it on the answer, we always abandon `@` in PHP

Comment: I don't like using `@` too :)

Comment: Never supress warnings with `@`. It's like covering sh** with leaves, it will just look a little better, but still stink all the same. Plus the error message will appear in the logs anyway.

Comment: @emix, how about using it in dynamic arrays keys maybe?

Comment: Just stick to `isset` or `empty`. The `??` operator was introduced to shorten the common `isset($_GET['key') ? $_GET['key'] : 'defaultValue'`. The `empty` will not complain if a variable is not declared, which is your case exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `??` operator twice.

```
$foo = [];
$baz = [];
$bar = $baz[$foo['bar'] ?? ''] ?? '' ;
```

[See it in action on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bnFPV)

Answer (score 1):

When you are not sure whether a variable/array element exists, you will need to use isset to avoid errors. You can use the @ operator to avoid displaying error messages, but the error will just not be displayed, it will occur nonetheless. Avoid the @ operator when possible.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to that question is that you cannot achieve the same behavior with `??` simply because the operator passes only 1 argument to isset() and you need to pass multiple ones.

The solution with `@` is really bad and should be avoided. So I suggest just using `isset()` even for code readability.